# Question On Hill's equation for even functions

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Hi guys I am trying to understand some properties of Hill's equation where we define it is as such

$$(P(x)y')'+Q(x)y=0$$
Where both $P(x), Q(x)$ even $P(-x)=P(x)$ and periodic of period T, $P(x+T)=P(x)$. What I am struggling with is showing the following: Let  $y_1,y_2$ be linearly independent solutions then:

1) For any solution $y(x)$ $y(-x)$ is also a solution.
2) If $y_1$ is even then $y_2$ is odd
3) Every even solution has to be multiple of $y_1$.

My work so far is as goes
1) Consider
$(P(-x)y'(-x))'+Q(-x)y(-x)=0$ then we can clearly use that $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are even thus we have $(P(x)y'(-x))'+Q(x)y(-x)=0$. Thus we can see that $y(-x)$ is a solution.

2) I tried reading the book [Hill's Equation](https://books.google.com/books?id=XwEMurjYXvYC&pg=PR2&lpg=PR2&dq=Hill%27s%20equation%20by%20Magnus%20and%20Winkler&source=bl&ots=dJf-3N6GJ9&sig=FSVIAlIfrnnkS53CT0xRZ2cYrfY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiuyof8i8_PAhVB6GMKHYTFD3EQ6AEIPTAF#v=onepage&q=Hill%27s%20equation%20by%20Magnus%20and%20Winkler&f=false). The things was argued there but I do not understand how the initial conditions imply it in general for every $x$.

Thank you for your time guys.